# Add x% width to a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a kind of "loading bar" that is initially at 0% width.

```
<div id="loading_bar"></div>
```

Now I also have a form... that has different types of fields...

For example I have 5 selectboxes... now if I select something from selectbox nr1 ... the  must change from 0% to 20%... and now if I select something from selectbox nr2 another 20% are added to that div width... and so on...

I wrote this code but it gives me pixels instead of percents...

```
$("#loading_bar").css("width", "+=20");
```

How can I write so it ADDS 20% instead of 20px..? Can somebody please help... Thank you

---

EDIT/UPDATE

I have 5 selectboxes...

for each selectbox I have an IF ELSE statement..

for example: IF selectboxnr1 is selected ADD 20% to the div... if it was DESELECTED(not selected)... MINUS 20% back

and so on for every 5 selectboxes..

P.S. I write MANUALLY the % for each selectbox... so for example I write

```
$("#loading_bar").css("width", 20+"%")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two steps:

```
var new_width = $("#loading_bar").css("width") * 1,2
$("#loading_bar").css("width",new_width+"px")
```

Replace `px` with `%` if you are using that in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing += when I'm assuming you have the actual correct percentage somewhere?

```
$("#loading_bar").css("width", percentage+"%")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. that was it. I added ->

$("#loading_bar").css("width", 20+"%")

and it works fine

Comment: @AlexandruVlas: That doesn't add `20%`. It reduces it to `20%` of the current size. That's not what you asked for. And if that's what you wanted, why would you do `20 + "%"` instead of `"20%"`?

Comment: one more thing... I have an IF and ELSE... so something like IF selectbox nr1 is selected ADD 20% else (if it's not selected, or have been selected and then deselected again MINUS 20% that were added..) could you give me a hint how to achieve this? should I just write "-" instead of "+" .. ?

Comment: @user2736012 "width: 20%" sets the width to 20% of the container that it's in... which is what I assume Alex meant.

Comment: @HansZ: Ah, Alex doesn't understand the mathematical concept of addition. Yes, you're probably right. He wants to set it to certain percentages of a fixed number.

Comment: @AlexandruVlas store your percentage somewhere, i.e. `var percentage`. On select, `percentage += 20; $("#loading_bar").css("width", percentage+"%");`

Comment: @user2736012 - no, it actually adds the 20% to the div.. like I wrote in description the initial width of the div is 0%.... so it adds 20 and it becomes 20% from 0%...

Comment: @AlexandruVlas: Adding `20%` to the width of a `div` with a starting width of `0` results in a `div` with a width of `0` because `0 x .2 = 0` and `0 + 0 = 0`.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

Update, you can make a variable to increment and the do this

```
    $("#loading_bar").css({width, With+"%"})
```

Or

```
    $("#loading_bar").css("width",With+"%")
```

Comment: That always sets it to 20%.

Comment: Oh, your are rigth, let me fix it

Answer (score -1):

You could be cleaner and write a CSS statement for it

```
.width-20percent {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Then add the class instead:

```
$("#loading_bar").addClass('width-20percent ');
```

This will also allow you to easily re-use it on other elements and make it so you only need to edit one time if you change your mind. .

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This just makes it 20% forever.